# Why apache doesn't restart after configuring SSL?

Tags: apache-http-server, ssl

I've installed apache2 and then configure it to work with SSL following [this](http://www.tc.umn.edu/~brams006/selfsign.html) and [this](http://www.tc.umn.edu/~brams006/selfsign_ubuntu.html) tutorials, the problem becomes when I try to restart the service, the following error throws:

`(98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:443
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs`

the output of `netstat -anp | grep 443` just display firefox listening and anything else, how could I solve this and get the service running??

The ouput of `ps -Af|grep <firefox PID>` is:

`root      1949     1 11 18:42 tty1     00:20:55 /opt/firefox/firefox-bin
root      2025  1949  4 18:43 tty1     00:08:39 /opt/firefox/plugin-container /root/.mozilla/plugins/libflashplayer.so -greomni /opt/firefox/omni.ja 1949 true plugin`

after closing firefox and then cheking again for port 443 the output is:

`tcp        0      0 10.32.208.179:38923     74.125.139.155:443      TIME_WAIT   -

tcp        0      0 10.32.208.179:45706     74.125.139.113:443      TIME_WAIT   -

tcp        0      0 10.32.208.179:40456     74.125.139.156:443      TIME_WAIT   -

tcp        0      0 10.32.208.179:56823     69.171.227.62:443       FIN_WAIT2   -

unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     12443    1721/dbus-daemon    @/tmp/dbus-8ee35rmOOS`

Seeing the error logs, which are not at the time when I'm doing this, the last errors are:

`[Tue Oct 02 18:41:54 2012] [error] Init: Unable to read server certificate from file /etc/apache2/ssl/sever.crt
[Tue Oct 02 18:41:54 2012] [error] SSL Library Error: 218529960 error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag
[Tue Oct 02 18:41:54 2012] [error] SSL Library Error: 218595386 error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_ITEM_EX_D2I:nested asn1 error`

Comment: What is listening? Firefox? Left to the `firefox` there is a PID. Try ps -Af|grep <that PID> and see what is this exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [link](http://www.tc.umn.edu/~brams006/selfsign.html) pointed by you:

Complete these steps.

Comment: @poz2k4444 You need to take `server.crt` and put it into `/etc/apache2/ssl/`

Comment: Could you please repeat the steps starting from "Generate a server key and request for signing (csr)." of 1b)

Comment: I've done everything again and it works, well kinda, I can access to the page but it says it's not secure, what could be the problem?

Comment: @poz2k4444 try https :  //server/page (without spaces)

Comment: I'm trying with localhost, `https://localhost` and it doesn't work

Comment: `netstat -lntp` ?

Comment: `19047/apache2   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN`

Comment: check its errors.log and access.log

Comment: errors.log `[Wed Oct 03 00:10:57 2012] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Wed Oct 03 00:10:58 2012] [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `paco' does NOT match server name!?
[Wed Oct 03 00:10:58 2012] [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `paco' does NOT match server name!?
[Wed Oct 03 00:10:58 2012] [notice] Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.3.2-1ubuntu4.17 with Suhosin-Patch mod_ssl/2.2.14 OpenSSL/0.9.8k configured -- resuming normal operati$`

Comment: access.log `127.0.0.1 - - [03/Oct/2012:01:05:20 -0500] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 304 210 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686 on x86_64; rv:14.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/14.0.1"
`

Comment: your server name in certificate is not `localhost` you should access it by the server name in certificate

Comment: do I have to change something in configuration?

Comment: You should type in your browser the same name for host that you used to create the certificate. or recreate certificate using `localhost` as a hostname